# Trouble with using a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in Python and I know this question is pretty basic but I can't seem to find the solution from Googling.

I am writing a simple scraping script in Python and I am using BeautifulSoup for parsing. I am just stuck in using a variable to set the filename of my CSV write functions. say I have a variable called "category", how can I set that as the name of the CSV file?

```
category = "student"

with open('%category.csv', 'a') as csv_file:  
   writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
   writer.writerow([cname, caddress, ccontact])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) like this:

```
with open('{}.csv'.format(category), 'a') as csv_file:
```

**Output:**

```
>>> category = 'my_file'
>>> '{}.csv'.format(category)
'my_file.csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open(category + '.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
```

You do not substitute the variable like that. Read a basic book.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
with open('%s.csv' % category, 'a') as csv_file:
```

See [this informative article](https://pyformat.info/) for more on string formatting in Python.

Answer (score 1):

This task can be achieved by many ways and few of which are listed below :

1. String Concatenation .

   ```
   category = "student" 
   with open(category + '.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
   ```
2. String Formatting

   ```
    with open('%s.csv' % category, 'a') as csv_file:
   ```
3. Using `format()` function

   ```
   with open('{}.csv'.format(category), 'a') as csv_file:
   ```

I hope these all will work fine for you.

Best One is :-

```
category = "student.csv" 
with open(category, 'a') as csv_file:
```

The last one is simplest one , to change the name of file just change the value of variable.